# Access Denied When using php to link to another html page

Tags: php, html, apache, authentication, xampp

I'm fairly new to php/html so bear with me.

So in the home page of my website, the login link takes the user to either

1. The login page
2. The user page if they had already logged in

Before implementing this fully, I decided to check whether or not I could get a simple php link to work and im glad i did because it does not work.

I have currently:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'login.html';?>">Login</a>
```

This is supposed to go to login.html when clicked on but when you click on the link you get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkSNS.png)
Corresponding error log from XAMPP's appache error.log:

> [Thu Aug 09 21:51:30.257273 2018] [core:error] [pid 37376:tid 1948] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:49721] AH00127: Cannot map GET /poll/%3C?php%20echo%20%27login.html%27;?%3E HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/poll/Poll_home.html

If instead of the above code I put

```
<a href="login.html">Login</a>
```

then it works fine and links me to the login page. 
Any help would be great!

edit:

Problem is fixed by creating a new php file (test.php).

```
<a href="test.php">Login</a>
```

But when I try to make the link dynamic by changing the test.php to this:

```
<?php
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){ //if already logged on
    header("Location: login.html");
}
else{ //If not
    header("Location: sign-up.html");
}
exit;
?>
```

It always goes to login.html even when I am not logged on.

Comment: Your PHP hasn't been enabled yet or you are writing php code in html file.

Comment: I have a connect.php that is used to connect to a mysql database and that works fine so I don't think that's the issue? Also yes I am writing in an html file. Is that an issue? I thought it was fine if I put the <?php thing.

Comment: What you mean is that you writing php code in a file with extension `.html` ?

Comment: Yes. The only php code in the html is that echo.

Comment: On your login page... are you creating a session variable upon successful login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per error message

> Cannot map GET /poll/%3C?php%20echo%20%27login.html%27;?%3E HTTP/1.1
>   to file, referer: http://localhost/poll/Poll_home.html

It says that you are writting PHP code in Poll_home.html file, which is the problem, you should write PHP code in php file (i.e. Poll_home.php). When server see url file is html it will not execute it but send it content to user browser. so rename your file and check. It should work.

Comment: But I have seen people write php in html with the <?php ?> tags?

Comment: If you write php code in html file, then server treat it as normal text as part of html,  You  can verify it by seeing source code of your file, just right clicking and selected view source, you can see your php code.

Comment: So I wrote the php in a new file (test.php) and it does seem to work. <a href="test.php">Login</a>. But I get a new problem when I try to expand it and achieve the original goal (see edited post).

Comment: If this answered your original question you should mark it as the accepted Answer. If you have a new question you should ask a new question in a new post, rather than appending it to the question that has been answered

Answer (score 0):

if isn't working with php use this

```
<a href="<?='login.html';?>">login</a>
```

or use this

```
<a href="login.html">Login</a>
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work. I get the same error. As the for the second one yes that works but I need to expand this later on (I mentioned this at the beginning of the post) to make the link be either login.html or user.html which is why I nedd the php part.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to this so I dont know much haha.

Comment: there is no problem
do you setup **xampp** ??

Comment: Yea so it should automatically allow php to my knowledge